# Проверка input на наличие цифр

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

По задумке этот код должен выводить "hi", если строка состоит из цифр, но он выводит "hi" и в таких ситуациях 45645gh4, когда первый символ строки цифра. Мне нужно чтобы выполнялось условие если строка полностью состояла из цифр

```js
    var validInp =/['0-9']/;
    if(validInp.test($('.input').val())) console.log('hi');
```

Comment: `/^\d+$/` - начало строки, 1+ цифра, конец строки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалите одиночные кавычки, для задания диапазона они не нужны. Добавьте символ `+` после закрывающей скобки, чтобы совпадение включало одну и более цифр. Заключите `[0-9]+` в `^` (начало строки) и `$` (конец строки).

Вы можете использовать

```
var validInp =/^[0-9]+$/;
```

Можно использовать синонимичное в JavaScript выражение `/^\d+$/`.

```js
var validInp =/^[0-9]+$/;

$(function(){
        $("input").on('input', function(){
            if (validInp.test($(this).val())) {
               console.log('hi');
            } else {
               console.log('bye');
            }
        });        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input" value="" placeholder="Введите цифры">
```